# lldb fails to show sources

Tags: android-ndk, lldb

I'm debugging an Android application (fully native, C++-only) from Windows host. But the application is build under Linux, so path to source in `image lookup` looks like

```
LineEntry: [0x000077267b3f3140-0x000077267b3f3157): /home/user/src/xxx/Sources/xxx/libraries/interfaces/foo.cpp:61
```

But target.source-map works in unexpected way.

```
(lldb) settings set -- target.source-map "/home/user/src/xxx" "C:/Users/test/src/yyy"
(lldb) settings show target.source-map
target.source-map (path-map) =
[0] "\home\user\src\xxx" -> "C:\Users\test\src\yyy"
(lldb) source list
(lldb)
```

So, `source list` returns nothing and in Process Monitor I see unsuccessful access to
C:\home\user\src\xxx\Sources\xxx\libraries\interfaces\foo.cpp

My configuration is

```
(lldb) version
lldb version 12.0.5 (/buildbot/src/android/llvm-toolchain/out/llvm-project/lldb revision c935d99d7cf2016289302412d708641d52d2f7ee)
  clang revision c935d99d7cf2016289302412d708641d52d2f7ee
  llvm revision c935d99d7cf2016289302412d708641d52d2f7ee
(lldb) platform select remote-android
(lldb) platform connect connect://localhost:5039
```

lldb is from android-ndk-r23. There is no issues with rest of lldb/lldb-server.

Interesting that gdb/gdbserver in same environment shows sources just fine with `set substitute-path`.

Is it some mistake on my side?

Comment: lldb always tries the original path first, and then tries the source map fallbacks, so it's isn't surprising that it tries to access the original Linux path (rooted at C: presumably).  But it should also be trying the substituted path.  You might try leaving the C: off the substitute path.  It looks like lldb is inferring that when it looks up the original path, so maybe that is making it not match.  OTOH, I don't know if I've heard of someone using the source map to go from a Unix path to a Windows path so that might just be a bug.  You might report this at http://bugs.llvm.org.

Comment: Do you find a solution ? I encounter the same problem

Comment: Well, I capitulated and moved the source tree to path where lldb expects it, like C:\home\user\src\xxx\Sources\xxx\libraries\interfaces\foo.cpp.